# How to set images at the ends of Gallery view(right and left)

Tags: android, android-gallery

I need help on placing images(back and forward images) at two ends of my gallery view. I have a gallery to list menus to scroll horizontally, and this gallery is in RelativeLayout how can I get the images at two ends of the gallery without scrolling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is in your question itself. put to `imageview` on both sides. the sample layout looks like below

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView....../>
    <Gallery .../>
    <ImageView .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would modify Praveen's answer a bit:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Gallery android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

android:layout_weight="1" in  is very important here.